# Complete list of all VIM commands

Tags: help-system, vim-development

I know the title should have been "God can you share all the knowledge in the Universe please ?"

But anyway it doesn't hurt if I ask...

Is there any compiled complete list of all VIM commands ? I want this by some reasons:

- I would like to know how little do I know about VIM
- I would like to groups commands I would like to learn/would be useful to me
- I may find some very interesting, less common commands that I wouldn't find any other way

I mean a long full list of all commands in one file. Like, ideally one command per line.

I know there are several files in help that list all commands completely, but in order to obtain a full list I would wave to compare intersecting lists and a huge list of texts and complementary infos.

If things like Neovim are possible, someone has to have a complete list somewhere or how people would know what to implement ?

**Edit**

With @mattb answer I could do what I wanted: compile a full list one command per line. Here is the link to the list in Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/xBRYzAw0

Comment: To the moderators: I couldn't think of a tag that would fit my question, so I used vim-development. Feel free to change it to a better one if you know of any.

Comment: Thanks, the list might be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### For all the gory details

From `:help index`:

> This file contains a list of all commands for each mode, with a tag and a
> short description.  The lists are sorted on ASCII value.

From `:help function-list`:

> There are many functions.  We will mention them here, grouped by what they
> are used for.  You can find an alphabetical list [with ':help functions'].
> Use CTRL-] on the function name to jump to detailed help on it.

From `:help reference_toc`:

> REFERENCE MANUAL: These files explain every detail of Vim.

#### For an overview

For a start there's `:help quickref` which gives an

> Overview of the most common commands you will use

That page has on the order of 1000 commands, settings, and... stuff.

And of course, from `:help`

```
BASIC:
quickref   Overview of the most common commands you will use
tutor      30-minute interactive course for beginners
copying    About copyrights
iccf       Helping poor children in Uganda
sponsor    Sponsor Vim development, become a registered Vim user
www        Vim on the World Wide Web
bugs       Where to send bug reports

Getting Started ~
|usr_01.txt|  About the manuals
|usr_02.txt|  The first steps in Vim
|usr_03.txt|  Moving around
|usr_04.txt|  Making small changes
|usr_05.txt|  Set your settings
|usr_06.txt|  Using syntax highlighting
|usr_07.txt|  Editing more than one file
|usr_08.txt|  Splitting windows
|usr_09.txt|  Using the GUI
|usr_10.txt|  Making big changes
|usr_11.txt|  Recovering from a crash
|usr_12.txt|  Clever tricks

Editing Effectively ~
|usr_20.txt|  Typing command-line commands quickly
|usr_21.txt|  Go away and come back
|usr_22.txt|  Finding the file to edit
|usr_23.txt|  Editing other files
|usr_24.txt|  Inserting quickly
|usr_25.txt|  Editing formatted text
|usr_26.txt|  Repeating
|usr_27.txt|  Search commands and patterns
|usr_28.txt|  Folding
|usr_29.txt|  Moving through programs
|usr_30.txt|  Editing programs
|usr_31.txt|  Exploiting the GUI
|usr_32.txt|  The undo tree

Tuning Vim ~
|usr_40.txt|  Make new commands
|usr_41.txt|  Write a Vim script
|usr_42.txt|  Add new menus
|usr_43.txt|  Using filetypes
|usr_44.txt|  Your own syntax highlighted
|usr_45.txt|  Select your language

Making Vim Run ~
|usr_90.txt|  Installing Vim
```

Comment: So what you're basically saying is that I have to compile the full list myself. Because as you probably know, many things in that lists aren't commands and there are many intersected commands between those lists. It's not a matter of just joining those help files... and the sheer size of VIM makes creating a full list from those files a prohibited effort.

Comment: I thought that maybe the development team of VIM or one of VIM clones could have already a full list somewhere.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Ah I see what you mean by commands now - and this exact thing does exist in vim's help. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I also saw that I wan't clear enough in the question. Improved it to clarify what I want.

Comment: That did it. After some filtering of the text I reached the number of 1278 commands. I'm disapointed. Expected at least a 5 number figure. :D
I read the whole file removing all the commands I already know. I got many years using VIM. I use VIM mode daily in Eclipse and really use it a lot. I got golden nunchucks at Shortcutfoo in VIM dojo. I found I know exactly 103 commands. Aprox. 8.06% of the full list. I see clearly there's no way to win this game. :D LOL

Comment: I've seen and used at least once pretty much 100% of the commands. But I've read the help pages "cover to cover", play Vim golf, and am a major contributor here. So it's possible but you need to be a fanatic. :) (All that being said, I don't have 100% of them memorized. Some are so specialized that the need to use them rarely if ever comes up. Taking a wild guess I'd say I know at least 80% off the top of my head and know that the functionality exists for at least half of the remainder.)

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira don't forget all the custom remaps, functions and plugins :)

Answer (score 1):

By all means the most authoritative source is [Vim source code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/370791465e745354d66696de8cbd15504cf958c0/src/ex_cmds.h#L115).

To generate full list of known commands in runtime:

```
:put =getcompletion('', 'command')
```

But note that the list includes both builtin and user-defined commands. As well as some constructs that are only allowed inside script files.

Comment: Interesting. In my vim that command generates a list of 596 lines. While I got the number 1278 command from index.txt.

Comment: I believe `getcompletion('', 'command')` will only list Ex commands (the ones you enter in the Command-line, after pressing `:`), it will not list Normal-mode commands, or keystrokes that execute special actions in Insert-mode.